# I need a basic Windows Server 2008 32-bit AMI on Amazon AWS

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ami

I need a basic, clean Windows Server 2008 32-bit (x86) AMI on Amazon AWS.

There are several on the Community AMI list but I am not sure which is a good one to get. Have you tried any of them? Are these community AMIs verified to be clean of virus/spyware/bitcoin-miners?

Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I'd be pretty careful with this. If you can use a modern windows version supplied by AWS that would be preferable.

Comment: There are no longer any Windows Server 2008 32-bit images in the AWS catalog. I need Windows Server 2008 32-bit for this application.

Comment: If you have the OS as VM you can import it into AWS, otherwise best not use AWS.